# Release Pipeline in Azure DevOps is success, When opening the URL, page is blank

Tags: azure, azure-devops

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bbaO.png)

I can view Release pipelines which is SUCCESS for me as shown below. I have tried to open the URl indifferent browsers such as Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge, both showing empty screen. I have verified that I have full access permissions and Visual Studio subscription also. Let me know if you ever faced such issue and a solution for this. Thanks

Comment: This requires a lot more information to answer. This could be an issue with your pipeline, I suppose, but it’s just as likely an issue with your code or your Azure App Service server configuration. What does your YAML look like? Are the expected files displayed on your Azure App Service afterwards? Does this work when you deploy directly using e.g., Visual Studio or msdeploy? What makes you think this is an issue with your pipeline, especially given that it reports that the code is successful?

Comment: In Visual studio code, Its working even in gh-pages its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
Publish using VS and try to access the url. Please find the below screenshot. Enter Azure server name. 
Still not working then DNS is not reachable. we have multiples scenario's. It will be multiple cases.
```

[image]